# CPComboBox in Cappuccino

Tags: cappuccino

It seems like there is no ComboBox component in Cappuccino framework.

I see that there are many widgets in Cappuccino that are not used very often (like Predicate Editor), but ComboBox is missing. Is it abandoned on purpose?
Is it possible to transform CPPopUpButton into Combobox somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CPComboBox actually *does* exist. It's just not in the latest stable release yet… 
Here's a link to the class: https://github.com/cappuccino/cappuccino/blob/master/AppKit/CPComboBox.j

We're working hard on getting the next major release out the door, please be patient or if you'd like to try out the latest release candidate you can here:
https://groups.google.com/d/topic/objectivej/svifpqxvjfA/discussion